# Bind variable performance issue

Tags: c#, ado.net, odp.net

Hi I have an insert query and when I check my database I see a lot different version of my query from

`V$sql_bind_capture` view. Problem is I have a column and this column is `varchar2` and take different values

Like Name field takes two different values.
My insert is same `insert into mytable values name=:name` but oracle create different instance due to this length issue

```
abcd length 4
abcdefgh length 8
```

And this consumes a lot of cpu in my oracle db side. Is it possible to prevent this issue?

Comment: Sounds like correct behavior. CPU usage is environmental. How do you can blame a query by data in this view?

Comment: I have a specific cluster,and only this kind of insert run on it.And I check V$sql_bind_capture view and see different types of each my query